# Init Date variable with null value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Simple question: how can init a Date value with a null value in VBA?

```
Dim DateStart As Date
DateStart = Null
```

doesn't work.

EDIT:

I was just wondering if it's possible. In the beginning of my code I want to set the value to blank, halfway it will be given a value in most cases, if not, later on I'll request the value and if still blank I have to take another action to get a value

Comment: I do not think you can, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Okay, you mean only a declaration and no (explicit) initialization?

Comment: Yes. When you declare something as date, its value is set, similarly if you declare something as boolean, its value is false. It is one of the advantages of declaring variables, only certain values are accepted.

Comment: I think it's strange you cannot explicitly initialize a variable. But it works, thanks! Unfortunately I can't set the question to "answered" because you commented, not answered

Comment: The only problem is if 12/30/1899 is a valid data in your application, as that's what 0 is.

Comment: VBA variables are initialized automatically to whatever the "empty" value would be for that particular data type. Numeric variables initialize as Zero, string as zero-length-string, etc. Variants are more complicated, but you should never use a variant except for a specific purpose.

Comment: This is what the Access help says:

"When variables are initialized, a numeric variable is initialized to 0, a variable-length string is initialized to a zero-length string (""), and a fixed-length string is filled with zeros. Variant variables are initialized to Empty. Each element of a user-defined type variable is initialized as if it were a separate variable."

So no explicit information about dates

Comment: 12/30/1899 is no problem for my application

Comment: Dates are stored as doubles, so implicitly, what you quote does answer the question. If you don't understand how dates are actually stored, then you should work with dates as little as possible.

Comment: Strange comment. Why should you have to know how data types internally are stored to work with them?

Comment: In the case of dates, any form like "10/2/2010" is a presentation-level display format. It's not the actual data stored there, which instead is 40219. Knowing this is important so you can realize that with different date format settings in your Control Regional Settings, the same underlying value in the data field may display as different things. For instance, with US settings, Short Date would display 40219 as 2/10/2010, and with British settings as 10/2/2010. The underlying stored value is the same, all the differs is the display format.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the different date format settings but my original question was if there is a (higher-level) way to set a variabele of type Date to "Null". But there isn't I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe you can do this, try

```
If datestart = 0 Then
```

Comment: Yes, it works. You already said it yourself in your previous comment